# Webmethod can't remove Object { d: "" }

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webmethod

What I want to do is instead of sending `Object { d : "{"FileID":"1213"}" }` send `"{"FileID":"1213"}"`

My current code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[ScriptService]
partial class testing_class : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["FileID"] = Request.QueryString["FileID"];

    }

    public static string returnJSON(object o)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(o);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string CurrentFile()
    {
        var d = new { FileID = "123" };
        return returnJSON(d);
    }


};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft stack Json serializers are pretty much obsolete and should be avoided at all costs. Instead you should be using (and newer .NET Web stack already is by default) [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) implementation.

If you don't have it installed you can do so by running `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` in your NuGet console window. Also make sure you are `using Newtonsoft.Json;`.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string CurrentFile()
{
    var d = new { FileID = "123" };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
}
```